# How do I retrieve latitude and longitude from a database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have an application in which I have to retrieve latitude and longitude from local database when the respective location is selected in tree view and that place has to be shown on the google map, in code behind I have the code for tree view database connectivity and code for google map is in javascript...

Now how I m going to do this...?

plz help me with this question or provide helpful links....

Thank you...

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Actually i am novice to asp.net,but I was wondering if i could call javascript function in asp.net webpage but I was not successfull in dat,even though I was looking for geocode and all that stuff but it is not for real time user and also by researching on dis topic I came across to make user control for google api bt its all about formatting and placing the map but my main question again remains the same ,how to get the values from database dynamically into map or how to call the function from javascript in asp.net,now i am trying for AJAX..if it helps me...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution to my problem... I simply called the load map function (which was written in javascript ) from treenode changed event handler in my code behind by rendering a script and using RegisterStartupScript()... The final code looks like this :

```
 protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conn = @"Data Source=RESHMA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=reshma;Integrated Security=True";
        string str = "select Lat,Lng from ChildTable where ChildName='"+TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text+"';";
        string inv;
        SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(conn);
        scon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(str, scon);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ada.Fill(ds, "ChildTable");
        var lat = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
        var lang = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1];
        inv = "<script type='text/javascript'>loadGmap(" + lat + "," + lang + ");</script>";
        Page.RegisterStartupScript("inv", inv);

    }
```

Comment: dint understand anything...while answering a question pls ensure that a person facing the same problem can read your answer and get something out of it

Answer (score 1):

I think [Google Maps API Examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/) + [15 Useful jQuery Google Maps Plugins, Tutorials and Resources](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/06/query-google-maps.html) must be helpful for you.